# C++ how to write header file prototype for a function that accepts an array of object pointers.

Tags: c++

Header file prototype (.hpp) is giving a g++ compiler error - no matching function type in header file. What it the correct way to write the prototype (or function parameter)? I've tried oh so many combinations...

```
void myClass( Objects (*)[] );
```

Implementation file function definition (.cpp)

```
void myClass::myFunction( Objects *ptr2object_Array ) {

  /* do stuff */ }
```

Looked thoroughly for the answer here and elsewhere... Thanks. Aware of the  vector lecture, I'm stuck with an array of object pointers.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to be passing around C style arrays, rather than e.g. `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: `Objects (*)[]` is not the type of an array of object pointers; it's the type of a pointer to an array of objects.

Comment: @Cubic - I'm not sure what the difference is on C style arrays.  It's an array of pointers to inherited class objects of an abstract class, if that helps...

Comment: @Chris The difference is that C++ vectors and arrays are easier to use and don't require weird syntax that has you second guessing all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function signatures need to match exactly:

```
void myClass( Objects (*)[] );

void myClass::myFunction( Objects (*ptr2object_Array)[] ) {

  /* do stuff */ 
}
```

Simple pointers like `Objects *ptr2object_Array` aren't the same as arrays of pointers.

Comment: Thanks!! I knew that, but just couldn't get the right combo.